# i'm using django 1.1 with python 2.7. cant display pdf in browser it pops a notification for download

Tags: python, django, pdf, browser

```py
if pdf:
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %(user_name)
    content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
    download = request.GET.get("download")

    return response

return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

This is the code views.py, a part of it. I have tried many things. Even the pdf stored on my pc locally can only be downloaded and does not display. I used  also.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly (if you expect to get any help, that is).

Comment: Add `response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename,)` before returning the `response`. Right now your lines `filename ... download = ...` don't do anything.

Comment: I solved it actually.

Answer (score -1):

The suggestion from dirkgroten works.

> Add response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename,) before returning the response

For people who might have the same problem make sure that:

1. You have content-disposition set an inline
2. Set content_type as application/pdf

For me originally it didnt work because I had the content_type as vnd.ms-word which is not browser compatible